# OctoberCMS: How to prevent a form filed from being saved into database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I've got a form fields definition file like the following:

```
fields:
    pivot[hall]:
        label: Hall
        type: text
        span: auto

    pivot[booth]:
        label: Booth
        type: text
        span: auto

    booth_picker:
        label: Select Booth
        type: boothpicker
        span: full
```

The third field is only a form widget which provides a convenient visual way to set the value of `booth` field. Therefore, I do not need the `booth_picker` field to be submitted and saved into database because there is no such field in the table. Only `hall` and `booth` need to be submitted and saved. I am currently getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'booth_picker'
>   in 'field list' (SQL: update `users` set `updated_at` = 2016-12-15
>   13:14:44, `booth_picker` = where `id` = 37)"

How can I prevent this helper field from being submitted? Or maybe there is a way of removing this field before the model is saved into database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to add underscore before your field name (new October Cms feature so perhaps you need to upgrade it to version 382)

like that `_booth_picker`

*edit* : im not sure but it seems this feature doesnt work with checkbox field :-(

Comment: Thank you buddy it solved my problem :) That should be documented somewhere.

Comment: i see that in the backend. When you want to upgrade your version, you have the release list (number version + explanation). Don't find to another place

Comment: I can see that this feature was added in [build 374](http://octobercms.com/changelog): *Form fields beginning with an underscore (_) are purged automatically and no longer saved to the model.*

Answer (score 2):

We can define field names inside `purgeable` property.

> Purged attributes will not be saved to the database when a model is created or updated. To purge attributes in your model, apply the October\Rain\Database\Traits\Purgeable trait and declare a $purgeable property with an array containing the attributes to purge.

```
    /**
     * @var array List of attributes to purge.
     */

    protected $purgeable = ['booth_picker'];
```

[Reference](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/traits#purgeable)